# Diagonal Star Challenge, not understanding it's concept?

Tags: java, loops

So below is a solution of a diagonal star challenge, which basically prints out stars based on the value assigned to the given parameter. Now I understand how nested loops functions, `i` will be compared with the index of `j`, but what I don't understand is, how is it printing out stars in a each row when there is only 1 if statement? If the loop meets one of it's conditions should it not just print out 1 star on each row? Why is it creating so many different patterns from just a single if statement?

```java
public static void printSquareStar(int number) {
    if (number < 5) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Value");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < number; j++) {
                if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == j || i == (number - 1) ||
                    j == number - 1 || i + j == (number - 1)) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                //none of these operations work then just leave a space
                //on that column
                else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            //creates a new row
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
*****
** **
* * *
** **
*****
```

Comment: *"should it not just print out 1 star on each row?"* --- No, because `print("*")` just prints the star, but doesn't go to the next line. `println()` will make the following `print()` calls print on the next line (`ln` is short for line), and the `println()` call is *outside* the `j` loop. The `j` loop prints stars and spaces on a single line, then `println()` ends the line, and the `i` loop will continue on to the next line to be printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your If statement it prints a * I or j fits the criteria. the || is or, so it is saying if (i == 0 or j == 0 OR i == j OR i == (number - 1)
OR j == number - 1 OR i + j == (number - 1)) then print a *, but if I or j doesn't not fit that print a space. You could have an if else for every other case which would make it easier to read.

Comment: I understand that, but my point is if i ==0 || j==0 || i ==j then thats 3 possible stars for the first line right? So should it not be * * * * 4 stars (including the first loop) instead of 5 stars * * * * * ?

Comment: It will also pass the conditions if j = 4 since number - 1 would be 4 in the case above, making I == 0, j == 0, I == j,  j == number - 1, and I + j == number - 1 will all pass the condition and print *.

Comment: Oh right, I see now, that makes sense, I feel so stupid haha. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! If my answer helped could you accept it as the answer?